# video has lagged on android installed on raspberry pi 3

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3

I install android on raspberry pi 3 from https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-android-raspberry-pi/
everything is ok except play video. when I play a video, the problem started and video plays very slowly until freeze.

I try to change config file from SD card but It is not different

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase GPU memory to 128 in the raspberry pi.

Comment: It's already on 256. I decrease that to 128 but it's working randomly